# Is there any way to make webpages fit my 1024×768 screen?

Tags: display, resolution, webpage

These days a lot of web pages are suited for wide screen monitors, but despite living in 2015 I still use a 1024×768 CRT monitor! So other than buying a new monitor is there any way to make web pages fit to my screen?

I think some possible ways might be

- writing a userstyle code (stylish)
- using an extension

Can anyone help me here with this issue?

I’m on a windows 7 Ultimate machine, all my apps are updated regularly, so I’m using the latest version of Chrome, and for example, even this Super User website (a handy example) has a scroll in the bottom which means that it doesn’t actually fit my screen.

Comment: 0_0. What resolution would this be?

Comment: Websites designed with Bootstrap will fit to your screen, but if not they wont really fit :(

Comment: @shapperd  But I saw lots of written stylish code that would do that to many websites.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  1024*768.

Comment: That's more your issue than widescreen/not widescreen-ness

Comment: no website should be wider than 1000px at minimum. if a website does not fit theyre badly programmed! a website should be responsive and gladfully a lot of websites use frameworks like bootstrap, so you should be fine visiting those. an the other hand, if you use old software with your old monitor, you should update something :)

Comment: I've seen a lot of userstyle codes that change the size of the screen to fit different resolutions, there're a lot of them in userstyle. I say if there's a global element for resolution in the codes(e.g css), could we change it to fit a certain resolution.